# aggregate over rows for many columns

Tags: r, aggregate

I have a large dataframe in the same format as `d` below, with count data for three columns nested within two different factors.

```
elevation   distance    sp1 sp2 spn
1500    0   2   2   5
1500    0   2   1   5
1500    50  2   2   5
1500    50  2   2   6
2000    0   9   2   5
2000    0   7   2   2
2000    50  4   3   6
2000    50  4   3   4
```

Notice that there are two replicate rows for each level of factor `d$distance`.

I would like to aggregate those replicate rows for each distance level within each elevation by summing in each column, so it ends up like this:

```
elevation   distance    sp1 sp2 spn
1500    0   4   3   10
1500    50  4   4   11
2000    0   16  4   7
2000    50  8   6   10
```

I can do it easily for one column, eg `sp1`.
`d2 <-data.frame(aggregate(sp1 ~ elevation + distance, data = d, sum))`

Can I avoid a `for` loop to get a new dataframe in the same format that includes all columns `sp`, `sp2`, `spn`?  Trying to adapt various other solutions I have seen online have ended in failure because certain bits of my own brain are missing. Thanks.

Comment: [How to make a great reproducible example in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610)

Comment: @shayaa is there something I can add that will help you answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `summarise_each` from `dplyr`.  It would be fast and efficient.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(elevation, distance) %>% 
   summarise_each(funs(sum))
#  elevation distance   sp1   sp2   spn
#      <int>    <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1      1500        0     4     3    10
#2      1500       50     4     4    11
#3      2000        0    16     4     7
#4      2000       50     8     6    10
```

Or another option is `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, lapply(.SD, sum) , by = .(elevation, distance)]
```

---

A `base R` approach would be with `aggregate` would be to use `.` to specify all the columns except the ones specified in the rhs of `~`.  But, on a large dataset, this would be slow.

```
aggregate(.~elevation+distance, df1, sum)
#   elevation distance sp1 sp2 spn
#1      1500        0   4   3  10
#2      2000        0  16   4   7
#3      1500       50   4   4  11
#4      2000       50   8   6  10
```

NOTE: If there are NA values, use `na.rm = TRUE` from the `sum`.

As @user2100721 suggested, we can also use `by` from `base R`

```
by(df1[3:5], df1[1:2], FUN = colSums)
```

The output will be a `list` and it can be converted to matrix by `rbind`ing the `list` elements.

Comment: thanks, very elegant solutions, and so quickly.  the `base R` worked well. I had trouble getting the `dpylr` solution to work: `Error: ‘sum’ not meaningful for factors`. Very grateful.

Comment: Because akrun's data is not the same as yours.

Comment: @ptenax I thought your 'sp1', 'sp2', 'spn' columns are `numeric`.  Can you check the `str(df1)`?  You may have a `factor` class column.  One way  would be to convert to numeric and then do sum i.e. `as.numeric(as.character(.))`

Comment: @ptenax try `df1 %>%
   group_by(elevation, distance) %>% 
   summarise_each(funs(sum(as.numeric(as.character(.)))))`

Comment: @akrun yes I did have an additional column in my real data that was a factor.  Thanks everyone for comments.

Comment: @user2100721  What do you meant by `with` and `by`?  You meant `by(df1[3:5], df1[1:2], FUN = sum)`